# How to place buttons horizontally in a form

Tags: html, css

In my angular app I have a typical data entry form with the following three buttons at the end:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <button id="button1id" name="button1id" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitRequest()">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <button id="button2id" name="button2id" class="btn btn-default" >Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <button id="button3id" name="button3id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, all 3 buttons are stacked vertically.
What is the CSS syntax to place all 3 of them horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use:

```
.form-group {
    float:left;
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2qVYk/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Removed `<br>` and the extra `<div>` tags

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <button id="button1id" name="button1id" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitRequest()">Save</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <button id="button2id" name="button2id" class="btn btn-default" >Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <button id="button3id" name="button3id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .form-group {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SMFuF/)
To remove whitespace between buttons refer [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

---

**UPDATE JAN 2024:**
`display: flex;` would be a better option these days

Answer (score -1):

Do not surround the buttons with div elements

```
<div class="form-group">
<button id="button1id" name="button1id" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitRequest()">Save</button>
<button id="button2id" name="button2id" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
<button id="button3id" name="button3id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```